# What is the difference between passing a function as a prop with or without parentheses in React?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui

This is probably something that I should know but I don't quite understand the behavior of my component when I pass a function without parentheses. Here's my component code.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import LoginButton from './LoginButton';
import LogoutButton from './LogoutButton';

class Header extends Component {
  renderButton() {
    switch (this.props.auth) {
      case null:
        return
      case false:
        return <LoginButton />
      default:
        return <LogoutButton />
    }
  }



handleTitleClick() {
    return(
      <Link to={this.props.auth ? '/classes' : '/'}>
        QueueMe
      </Link>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const styles = {
      title: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
      },
    };

    return(
      <AppBar
        title={<span style={styles.title}>QueueMe</span>}
        onTitleClick={this.handleTitleClick()}
        iconElementRight={this.renderButton()}
        showMenuIconButton={false}
      />
    );
  }
}

/*
 * @input: redux state
 * Allows the component to access certain piece of the state as props
 * Reducers determine the key in the state
 */
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { auth: state.auth };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

For my `onTitleClick` property in `<AppBar>`, I get the expected behavior when I pass it `handleTitleClick()` but when I pass it `handleTitleClick` and click it, I get an error that says `Cannot read property 'auth' of undefined`. What exactly is the difference here that causes the `handleTitleClick` not to be aware of the state?

Comment: ReactJS doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-my-function-being-called-every-time-the-component-renders

Comment: have you checked to see what `this` is equal to inside of `handleTitleClick`?

Comment: @RaphaMex this is exactly what I was thinking but I got the undefined error when I passed the function without parentheses

Comment: @DanO For some reason the state is not part of `this` when I pass the function without parentheses but it is when I pass it with parentheses, not sure why it behaves like so and how to go around it

Comment: Without parentheses you're not actually calling the function. A function name without the parentheses is a reference to the function. Read more  https://teamtreehouse.com/community/why-do-we-call-the-functions-without-parentheses-ie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good question! There are a few things wrong going on here. Javascript `this` can be a real pain. The problem is that your functions are not bound.

When you write `onTitleClick={this.handleTitleClick()}` you are immediately invoking the function at compile time. When you pass it `handleTitleClick` when you are providing an unbound function, it has no `this` defined.

There are two potential solutions, you can either define

```
handleTitleClick = (event) =>
    return(
      <Link to={this.props.auth ? '/classes' : '/'}>
        QueueMe
      </Link>
    );
  }
```

This makes handleTitleClick an arrow function, arrow functions bind their `this` to the closure that they were created in.

If you don't like using the IIFE way, you can always use

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.handleTitleClick = this.handleTitleClick.bind(this)
}
```

Check this out if you're still stuck.
https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Comment: Amazing, this makes sense now!

Answer (score 2):

You need to bind `this` to your component.

```
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.handleTitleClick = this.handleTitleClick.bind(this);
}
```

After this you can call without the parenthesis. Actually when you call with parenthesis you actually execute the function on render which may not actually the thing you want. You want to call the function only on click not on render. So use without parenthesis and bind your call in the constructor.

```
<AppBar
    ...
    onTitleClick={this.handleTitleClick}
    ...
  />
```

Comment: I prefer the new short way if supported: `handleTitleClick = () => {`