# What is the difference between onClick={increase} and onClick={()=>{increase()}} in React JSX?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I did a search and didn't find any results, so I'm asking here.

Comment: This really depends on how `increase` is defined. If it's a proper react input event handler, the latter will cause an error

Comment: You can refer this link as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49163972/what-is-the-difference-between-passing-a-function-as-a-prop-with-or-without-pare/49164085

Answer (score 3):

*If* the `increase` function takes no arguments, there is no difference.

The only way there *would* be a difference would be if the component in which this prop is defined used the value returned from inside the `onClick` function. For example, for the general case:

```
<Foo fn={fn} />
```

```
<Foo fn={() => { fn() }} />
```

Those two are not equivalent, because the first will return the return value of `fn` to Foo, and the second will return `undefined` to Foo. If Foo uses the return value of its `fn` prop, you'll see a difference.

But for the `onClick` prop in React, the [return value doesn't matter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49856490), and is ignored - so you may as well use `onClick={increase}` to save on a few characters.

*If* the `increase` function *does* take arguments, then doing

```
onClick={increase}
```

will pass along the click event to the function, but

```
onClick={() => { increase() }}
```

will not pass anything to the function.

(to pass the event to the function with the anonymous inline form, you'd need `onClick={(e) => { increase(e) }}`)

Answer (score 0):

the difference is that:

```
onClick={increase}
```

only called the "increase" function, you can not pass an argument except "Event" to "increase" function by this method, and also you can call only this one function,
but when you use:

```
onClick={()=> {
increase(argument1, argument2,...);
secondFunction();
thirdFunction();
//and so many other functions
}
}
```

you can pass arguments to your functions, and also you can call other functions as well.

Comment: `onClick={increase}` **does** pass an argument to the `increase` function; the `Event`

Comment: Event always passed by default, you can't pass your desire argument by this way.

Answer (score 0):

One addition to `CertainPerformance`'s answer -
Using `onClick={increase}` , we can pass a memoized version of the callback by passing the function to `useCallback` hook.

Like,

```
const increase = useCallback(()=>{
   //some logic
},[])
...

<Foo onClick={increase} />
```

This helps in preventing unnecessary rendering of components on re-render of parent and thereby increasing performance.

While in the case of `onClick = {()=>{increase()}}`, re-rendering of the component will occur every time as new reference to the callback is created on every render of the parent component. Also, we cannot use `useCallback` here like
`onClick = {useCallback(()=>{increase()},[])}` as `useCallback` cannot be called inside a callback. We get the error - `React Hook "useCallback" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.`

Refer:
[Rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html),
[useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)